# Won't print the variable when its been changed. How do i fix this?

Tags: python

This is what im trying to do:
Using python or pseudo-code

Create algorithm for collection and summarisation of grades from school

At least 5 subjects

Different codes for different grades
A=6,B=5,C=4,D=3,E=2,F=1,U=0

If you get 20 points together or less for all subjects you get 0£

If you get 30 – you get £100

Differentiate it so you get different values depending on score you get, so for 21 points you would receive £110.

Im new to Python so sorry if im being stupid

Here's my code so far:

```
Grade_1=(input("What grade did you get in your first subject?:"))

Grade_2=(input("What grade did you get in your second subject?:"))

Grade_3=(input("What grade did you get in your third subject?:"))

Grade_4=(input("What grade did you get in your fourth subject?:"))

Grade_5=(input("What grade did you get in your fifth subject?:"))

Grades={Grade_1,Grade_2,Grade_3,Grade_4,Grade_5,}

print ("Your Grades are", Grades)

if Grade_1==A:
    Grade_1=6
    print (Grade_1)
```

Comment: Stack overflow is not a place for getting answers for class assignments. It is for coding problems.

Answer (score 0):

in your if statement you need quotation marks around strings, like this:

```
if Grade_1 == "A":
```

Also - when you make lists you use square brackets like this:

```
Grades=[Grade_1,Grade_2,Grade_3,Grade_4,Grade_5]
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry i'm new to python so im terrible :P

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your if condition doesn't seem to be correct. In Grade_1, you are actually taking a string value but you are comparing it with a **variable** A and not with a string 'A'. So fix your if condition to see the desired output. That is, your if condition must be "if Grade_1 == 'A':" and not "if Grade_1 ==  A".